# How to pose the constraint for binary variable to indicate if quantity is zero or greater than zero

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming

So if I have some quantity bounded i.e
$ 1-N \leq (p^i-p^{i+1}) \leq N-1,$ for $N\ge1 $. The quantity $p^i-p^{i+1}$ will be an integer as well.

I was trying to figure out how to pose the constraint so that if I have binary variable $b_i$, then
$ b_i=\begin{cases} 
      0 & (p^i-p^{i+1}) =0 \\
      1 & (p^i-p^{i+1}) >0
   \end{cases}
$

I attempted to pose it as

$\begin{align} b_i \geq (p^i-p^{i+1})\\
M(p^i-p^{i+1}) \geq b_i,
\end{align}$

for a large value of $M$ but this does not seem to be exactly what I'm looking for since the quantiy $(p^i-p^{i+1})$ could be negative.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated how to properly represent this constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$b_i \le p^i-p^{i+1} \le (N-1)b_i$$